# HttpWebRequest login with hidden input

Tags: c#, xaml, httpwebrequest, hidden-field

I'm trying to login in to a website using a HttpWebRequest in a Windows 8 Store Application. The login form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript:return FormSubmit();">
<div>
    <div>
        <span>gebruikersnaam</span>
        <input size="17" type="text" id="username" name="username" tabindex="1" accesskey="g" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>wachtwoord</span>
        <input size="17" type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="48" tabindex="2" accesskey="w" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" accesskey="l" value="inloggen" tabindex="4" class="button"/>
    </div>
    <!-- The following hidden field must be part of the submitted Form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="_s3E91853A-222D-76B6-16F9-DB4D1FD397B7_c8424159E-BFAB-EA2A-0576-CD5058A579B4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="credentialsType" value="ldap" />
</div>
</form>
```

I'm able to send out most of the required inputs except for the hidden input named "lt". This is a random generated code for security purposes so I can't hard-code it in my script. My current script is like this:

```
HttpWebRequest loginRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_URL_REDIRECT);
        loginRequest2.CookieContainer = CC;
        loginRequest2.Method = "POST";
        loginRequest2.Accept = "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*";
        loginRequest2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        loginRequest2.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate";
        loginRequest2.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-us";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(await loginRequest2.GetRequestStreamAsync());
        sw.Write("username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&_eventId=submit&credentialsType=ldap");
        await sw.FlushAsync();

        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)await loginRequest2.GetResponseAsync();
```

How can I get te content of the hidden input "lt" before doing the request?

Answer (score 0):

Using [HTML Agilty Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), you can use this code snippet to get the *Hidden Field* value:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(LOGIN_URL_REDIRECT);
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='lt' and @value]");
foreach (var node in nodes) {
    var inputName = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
    var inputValue = node.Attributes["value"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", inputName, inputValue);
}
```

Using Linq:

```
var nodes = from n in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
            where n.Name == "input" && 
                  n.GetAttributeValue("type", "") != "" &&
                  n.GetAttributeValue("name", "") == "lt" && 
                  n.Attributes.Contains("value")
            select new
            {
                n.Attributes["name"].Name,
                n.Attributes["value"].Value
            };

foreach (var node in nodes) {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", node.Name, node.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the webpage and get the random key and use the same key to call the second page, I wrote a software that can easily accomplish this, read it here http://innosia.com/Home/Article/WEBSCRAPER

If you don't want to use WebScraper, at least you need to use the Cookie aware class which is CookieWebClient found in the downloaded solution, using it should be something like this :

```
// Use Cookie aware class, this class can be found in my WebScraper Solution
CookieWebClient cwc = new CookieWebClient;
string page = cwc.DownloadString("http://YourUrl.com"); // Cookie is set to the key

// Filter the key
string search = "name=\"lt\" value=\"";
int start  = page.IndexOf(search);
int end = page.IndexOf("\"", start);
string key = page.Substring(start + search.Length, end-start-search.Length);

// Use special method in CookieWebClient to post data since .NET implementation has some issues.
// CookieWebClient is the class I wrote found in WebScraper solution you can download from my site
// Re use the cookie that is set to the key
string afterloginpage = cwc.PostPage("http://YourUrl.com", string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&lt={2}&_eventId=submit&credentialsType=ldap", userid, password, key));

// DONE
```